# Render List in a popup

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

In my controller I've added request handler like this. Then i'm rendering it in partial  like that - `<?= $product_list->render() ?>` I'm calling it in a popup on page, list renders and  pagination in it says -

> widget not bound

Also there is no search - how can i add it there? Sorry for my grammar - not a native speaker.

```
public function onAddItem(){
    set_time_limit(60*60*4);
    ini_set('memory_limit','4200M');
    $config = $this->makeConfig('$/feegleweb/octoshop/models/product/columns.yaml');
    $config->model = new Product();
    $config->recordOnClick = 'console.log(:id);';
    $config->recordsPerPage = 10;
    $config->showSearch = true;
    $widget = $this->makeWidget('Backend\Widgets\Lists', $config);
    $widget->bindToController();
    $this->vars['product_list'] = $widget;
    return $this->makePartial('items_list');
}
```

Comment: Now there is only search problem. How add search widget there?

Comment: hmm can you share whole error message or is it only that small ?